# How to horizontally align CSS :hover buttons inside a centered parent div?

Tags: html, css, hover, alignment, centering

I can't find a similar problem to this one.

I want to have two CSS `:hover` buttons horizontally aligned in a centered parent div (orange div), but it isn't working.

Centering:
The cursor-activated area (purple border) expands far beyond the buttons, covering much of the page. How can I format the cursor-activated area to match the size of the buttons' source `content:url()` without destroying the centering of the parent div? Using something like `position:absolute` doesn't seem to be the right solution.

Horizontal alignment:
`display: inline-block;` works only if I change the div id `#alpha a{` to `#alpha{` and `#beta a{` to `#beta {`. 

This way the buttons horizontally align but then I lose their functionality.

See/edit the example here:
http://dabblet.com/gist/0ec177e3a1191051cc3555ca958a6d20

A possible solution:
Certain styling is probably needed for `:hover` or something like `a:hover` so that the unexpectedly large cursor-activated area can be reduced to the same size as the button without effecting the centering from the parent div. I've had no luck with `position:absolute`.

Any insights?

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    margin: 0px; 
    border: 0px black;
    padding: 0px;
   }

   #parent {
    background-color: rgb(200,80,0) !important;
    width: 50vw;
    font-size: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);     
    text-align: center; 
    }

   a{
   border: 1px solid red !important;
   }  

   :hover{
   border: 1px solid purple !important;               
   }

            #alpha a{       
            border: 1px solid black !important;      
            max-width:7%;             
      content: url("https://cdnimages.opentip.com/thumbs/VLL/VLL-LET-A_130_130.jpg"); 
      display: inline-block;
     } 
    
     #alpha:hover a{ 
     border: 1px solid yellow !important;             
   max-width:7%;                
      content: url("https://cdnimages.opentip.com/thumbs/VLL/VLL-LET-D_130_130.jpg"); 
      display: inline-block;
     }            

            #beta a{ 
            border: 1px solid black;             
            max-width:7%;            
      content: url("https://cdnimages.opentip.com/thumbs/VLL/VLL-LET-B_130_130.jpg");
      display: inline-block;  
         } 

        #beta:hover a{
        border: 1px solid yellow !important; 
     max-width:7%;             
      content: url("https://cdnimages.opentip.com/thumbs/VLL/VLL-LET-D_130_130.jpg");
      display: inline-block;             
      }
```

```html
<div id=parent> 
    <div id="alpha"><a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="beta"><a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where do you want the purple border? @logoologist

Comment: I'm only using the border for reference. I want it to be no larger than the content:url. I was able to achieve that by using position:absolute for :hover, however that undoes the parent's centering.

Comment: `:hover` applies to each and every element so you have to be specific, try `a:hover`. As you already seem to have a yellow border on the links so purple border won't be visible. Is purple border for debugging purposes? If yes, you can use `!important`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to #parent

```
            display: flex;
            align-items:center;
            justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Chase, you're a hero. Your advice worked. The only other code I changed to solve the problem was  a{ max-width: 10vw;}  Solution is here: http://dabblet.com/gist/c4fbe3fad7026af25008c5affc47cb05